# python - How to use file as a Queue

Tags: python, file, buffer

I need to use a file as a *Queue* but I don't know how to start (also any other aproach is welcome), because I have a non-secure transmission between my device and a computer, and I need all the data to be saved until it is sent and successfully recieved. The DATA is a list which always holds the same type and amount of elements. I imagine something like this to be the file structure:

```
FILE
DATA 0 <- send_pointer 
DATA 1
DATA 2
DATA 3 
       <- new_item
```

So the code will look like:

```
while True:
    DATA = data_gather()
    FILE.write(DATA, new_item)
    new_item += 1
    x = FILE.read(send_pointer)
    if send_function(x):
        FILE.delete(send_pointer)
        send_pointer += 1
    else:
        print('error sending x')
```

I hope you understand my issue, my english is not the best.

**EDIT**
I installed this module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pqueue/0.1.1

But I don't know how to use it well. I can't find a way to delete the data I have already read from the file.

Thanks!

**EDIT 2**
Solved with pqueue.

Comment: You should consider using an actual message queue. It will handle access and persistence for you.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I understand the scope of queues, but I need this information to be secured if any power shutdown happens, and for my understanding a queue will not be safe and data can get lost.

Comment: It will be if you configure it correctly.

Comment: Can you help me more? is there any working module?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

offset = 0
while True:
    infile=open("./log.txt")
    infile.seek(offset)
    for line in infile:
        print line // do something
    offset=infile.tell()
    infile.close()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Only updates to log.txt are printed using this method

Comment: I don't want to get updates, but just one to put information at the bottom, and another to increment and delete the data, only when the send function was successful.

Comment: Deleting data from top of a file is a very expensive operation, you are better off maintaining a seek position and rolling over to another file after writing X entries. Once the entire file is read and processed we should delete the file.

Comment: Also if you want a distributed solution for this, you can look at Apache Bookkeeper